# Illegal instruction when using qemu and gdb-multiarch

Tags: arm, gdb, qemu

Hi I'm trying to debug arm binary using qemu and gdb-multiarch,
I'm 95% positive the binary is `armv5tej`.
I get the error `Illegal instruction` a couple of seconds after continuing the break in gdb.

**qemu-arm-static**

```
# chroot . /rootfs/qemu-arm-static -g 1234  /rootfs/test
...
...
```

qemu error:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

**gdb-multiarch**

```
$ sudo gdb-multiarch -q --nh -ex 'set architecture armv5te'   -ex 'file /rootfs/test ' -ex 'set sysroot /rootfs'    -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' 
The target architecture is assumed to be armv5te
Reading symbols from /rootfs/test...
(No debugging symbols found in /rootfs/test)
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
Reading symbols from /rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.3...
(No debugging symbols found in /rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.3)
0xff1ba8a0 in _start () from /rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.3
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
The program no longer exists.
```

i tried the following architectures in gdb-multiarch `armv5, armv5t, armv5te, armv5tej`
all gave the same error.

What is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the 'test' program exec another process? That's the only reason I can think of offhand why the SIGILL wouldn't be reported to the attached gdb.

Comment: Also, what QEMU version are you using?

Comment: Yes it does, it executes `ifconfig` when it crashes, why should it be a problem? how to prevent that? `qemu-user-static 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.3`

Comment: It's not a problem, it's just that your debug session is only of the first process, not of the ifconfig, so you don't get any information in the debugger about why it crashed. If you run ifconfig directly and look at that in the debugger then the debugger will be able to tell you what the instruction that caused the SIGILL is.

Comment: There is no exception when i run ifconfig with gdb... I get `ifconfig: SIOCSIFADDR: No such device` as output. I don't care if the ifconfig fail, i just want the main program will continue without sigill exception

Comment: Hmm. My next suggestion would be to turn on a bunch of the QEMU -d logging options (and redirect to a file with -D) and then it might become clearer what is causing the SIGILL.